# How to fill zero vectors with the answers from for loop?

Tags: matlab, octave

I created a zero vector named

```
result = zeros(1,20);
```

on GNU Octave GUI, and I want to fill the zeros with the integral estimation from the for loops.

```
a = 0;
b = 3;
f = @(x) sin(10 *x.^2);

for i = 20
    n = 2.^i;
    dx = (b - a) / n;
    left = a:dx: (b - dx);
    right = (a+dx) :dx:b;
    h1 = f(left);
    h2 = f(right);
    areas = (h1 + h2) ./ 2 .* dx;
    totalarea = sum(areas)
endfor
```

Could anyone please tell me how to fill the `result` matrix with the `totalarea` values from the for loop above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments:

```
result = zeros(1,20);
a = 0;
b = 3;
f = @(x) sin(10 *x.^2);

for i = 1:20 % make sure you loop from 1 to 20
    n = 2.^i; 
    dx = (b - a) / n;
    left = a:dx: (b - dx);
    right = (a+dx) :dx:b;
    h1 = f(left);
    h2 = f(right);
    areas = (h1 + h2) ./ 2 .* dx;
    totalarea = sum(areas);
    result(i) = totalarea; % put the totalarea in the i'th position in the result matrix
endfor
```